# Logic to use for checking a point inside a polygon using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy

I have polygon.shp and point.shp. I have to check certain attribute where if the point is inside a polygon it have to be True and if it is outside the polygon it has to be False.

I am new to ArcPy and I have no idea which logic to use to find this.

#i tried spatial join, but the thing is that so many points with True as their value got left out

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:/Desktop/New jersey_Completed'
outworkspace = 'C:/Desktop/Output'

Polygon = "C:/New_Jersey_BFP_Part-2.shp"
point = 'C:/New jersey_Completed/New_Jersey_20220224_Property_Points_Part-2.shp'
arcpy.AddField_management(point, "REST", "TEXT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
fields = ['point', 'Polygon']
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(point, fields) as cursor:
   
        # row[0] corresponds to the newly create 'REST' attribute..0 index
        # row[1] accesses the geometry of your point feature class.. 1 index
        if row[1].contain([0]):
            row[0] = 'True'
        else:
            row[0] = 'False'
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: I have tried Spatial join, but the thing is that In 1000 attributes only 800 gets as an output as True but i want to check all the points and the points which are not inside the polygon has to show an output as false

Comment: but there are like more than 200,000 polygons tho and my target feature is a polygon which would be kinda taking long for the output

Comment: There are a handful of ways to achieve this. Simply use select by location where a point intersects the polygon, set the attribute to True using field calculator (it will only update selected records), repeat except invert selection and set the rest to False.

Comment: It's rare when you'll get a query with a single cursor to return both a point *and* a polygon, so this code sample is a flight of fancy (and you appear to be updating a SearchCursor row, and failed to include the Boolean field in your `fields` list). While it is possible to use an UpdateCursor to select features in another layer and update accordingly, you're missing quite a bit of code to attempt that.

Answer (score 1):

The below is using ArcGIS Pro. If using ArcMap you will need to update the PYTHON3 to PYTHON_9.3 in the CalculateField

```
import arcpy

## path to your polygon shapefile
polygon = "path/to/polygon.shp"

## path to you point shapefile
point = "path/to/point.shp"

## the field to add to the point shapefile
## this will be filled in with True or False
field = "REST"

## add the field to the point shapefile
arcpy.AddField_management(point, field, "TEXT", "", "", 5, "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

## select all points that intersect a polygon
point_in_poly = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(point, "INTERSECT", polygon)

## update the attribute to True for the selection
arcpy.CalculateField_management(point_in_poly, field, "'True'", "PYTHON3")

## select all points that do not intersect a polygon
point_not_in_poly = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(point, "INTERSECT", polygon, invert_spatial_relationship=True)

## update the attribute to False for the selection
arcpy.CalculateField_management(point_not_in_poly, field, "'False'", "PYTHON3")
```

Comment: Thank you! i will try this and also im using ArcPro

Comment: It worked!! thank you, Clubdebambos